# Kafka Connect - Cannot ALTER to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{BYTES}, name='CreateUID', isPrimaryKey=true},

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I am using JDBC source connector to read data from a Teradata table and push to Kafka topic . But when I am trying to use JDBC sink connector to read Kafka topic and push to Oracle table it throws  the below ERROR. 
I am sure the error is because of the parameters `pk.mode` and `pk.fields` which I am not sure what to use.

My terradata has a primary key UserID+ DatabaseID . I have created the table in Oracle with the primay key as Userid+databaseID.

```
** ERROR Cannot ALTER to add missing field SinkRecordField{schema=Schema{BYTES}, 
name='CreateUID', isPrimaryKey=true}, as it is not 
optional and does not have a default value**
```

Below is my sink connector-

```
{name=teradata_sink
connector.class=io.confluent.connect.jdbc.JdbcSinkConnector
tasks.max=1
topics=TERADATA_ACCESSRIGHTS
connection.url=
connection.user=
connection.password=
auto.create=false
table.name.format=TERADATA_ACCESSRIGHTS
pk.mode=record_value
pk.fields=USERID+DATABASEID
auto.evolve=true
insert.mode=upsert
}
```

Please suggest how can I use the JDBC sink connector with the given primary keys.

Comment: Did you solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the schema of your target does not match the source. Since you have `auto.evolve=true` Connect tries to `ALTER` the target, and here it cannot for the error shown

```
`CreateUID`…is not optional and does not have a default value
```

Does that column exist in your target table as well as source?

Comment: Yes the column exists in my source and target table both also I tried with auto create.enable=false and created the same schema table as it was in teradata but it throws the above error.